# How our body parts are classified as Vata, Pitta and Kapha Dosha in Ayurveda?

Tags: vedas, belief, ayurveda, body

I am interested in knowing the science behind the classification because Ayurveda is based upon this foundation.
Even Astrology is also based upon these doshas.

Comment: @Tezz Air Element implies what are it's constituents? Same for Water and Solid Elements.

Comment: It is based on theory of Pancha Mahabhuta. I couldn't find a book which exactly explains this thing now. This book however sonehow discuss some concepts.http://www.ayurveda.hu/doc/2__dr_ch.pdf

Comment: It is not body parts that are classified as such. One's constitution is classified as such based on the movement of prana in the body.